# Random Float Generator

Tags: c++, random, floating-point

I'm learning c++ and I'm trying to generate a random float and seem to be having some difficulties.

I start by making a random int(), newRandom, between -100 and 100, then I take that newRandom and turn it into a random float, rand_X, between -1.0 and 1.0. The only caveat is I don't want rand_X to be between -0.2 and 0.2, in other words,

-1.0 <= rand_X <= -0.2 and 0.2 <= rand_X <= 1.0.

Here's my code,

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int newRandom() {
    int newRandom = 0;
    std::random_device rd; // obtain a random number from hardware
    std::mt19937 eng(rd()); // seed the generator
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> distr(-100, 100); // define the range

    newRandom = distr(eng);

    return newRandom;
}

float newRandomX() {
    float rand_X = newRandom() / 100.0f;
    for (int n = 0; n > 0; n++) {
        if (rand_X < 0.0f && rand_X > -0.2f) {
            rand_X = newRandom() / 100.0f;
        }
        else if (rand_X > 0.0f && rand_X < 0.2f) {
            rand_X = newRandom() / 100.0f;
        }
        else {
            return rand_X;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    float dir_x = newRandomX();
    std::cout << dir_x;
}
```

I usually set a break point at the closing bracket of main() and this is my output in the console window, **-nan(ind)**

As I said I'm learning the language so I'm probably doing something very silly.  Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: What is this `for (int n = 0; n > 0; n++)` ?

Comment: Why can't you just use [`uniform_real_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution)?

Comment: `for (int n = 0; n > 0; n++) {` fails the `n > 0` condition the first time it's checked, so the loop *never* runs. Hence, your function executes no `return` statement, and has undefined behaviour which ostensibly happened to manifest as `NaN` during your testing.  You can use `for ( ; ; )` for a loop that runs until `return`, `break`, `goto`, `throw`, `exit` etc. are encountered....

Comment: Other things you should be aware of: 1) you should not create and seed a new generator every time - make it static.  2) your `main` function should return a value (0, usually).  3) pay attention to your comparisons, and whether or not something should be `>` or `>=`, especially if you invert them like in the answer provided.

Comment: How do you create a static seed?  Would I make it a variable that's entered into the newRandow() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `newRandomX()` to this:

```
float newRandomX() {
    float rand_X = newRandom() / 100.0f;
    while(rand_X > -0.2f && rand_X < 0.2f) {
        rand_X = newRandom() / 100.0f;
    }
    return rand_X;
}
```

**Outputs:**

```
0.75
-0.93
-0.43
-0.82
```

Comment: Thank you!  This is exactly what I needed.  I knew that if I was repeating something that there was a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Your current code will only generated two decimal digits (note: rounded to nearest value that can be supported by the float format). To get a better distribution (i.e. more digits) you should extend the integer range to be much bigger and then divide by a higher number than 100.0f.

Further there is no need for a while-loop. I would recommend an if-statement instead.

Assume your newRandom generates an integer in range [-80:80] instead of [-100:100] then you could do something like:

```
float newRandomX() {
    float rand_X = newRandom() / 100.0f;
    if (rand_X < 0) {
        rand_X = rand_x - 0.2;
    } else {
        rand_X = rand_X + 0.2;
    }
    return rand_X;
}
```

As stated above I would also recommend a bigger integer range.